# Execute content.js script code from background.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Could you please help me how we can merge content.js script code in background.js script file and execute that content.js script code from background.js script?

Comment: Please clarify your question? Show us your code, what is content.js or background.js?

Comment: You don't need to merge anything. So long as `content.js` is included in the HTML page *before* `background.js`, then you can call the functions in content.js

Comment: My question is that, currently content.js script is retrieving information from web page and send it to background script in chrome extension but we need to merge that content.js script code in background.js script so all the things can do by background.js script, any idea how we can do that?

Comment: Without seeing the code it's impossible to say with certainty if what you want is possible but maybe you're looking for chrome.tabs.executeScript.

Comment: @wOxxOm, you mean that, we should try it with chrome.tabs.executeScript (execute content.js script) in backendscript.js script?

Comment: Most importantly I mean that we can't answer the question as it currently stands but you can investigate executeScript and see if it's simpler for you than to elaborate on the problem.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Thanks for your reply!, Can we execute content.js script from popup.js script file?

I have tried with below and its working fine but it executing in loop
`chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true}, function(tab){
 chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab[0].id, {code: content.js script code},function() {}
});`
Can I execute it at once when click on chrome extension icon?